# Use another database in datawriter Xenforo

Tags: database, model, xenforo

I have a model in Xenforo

```
public function newDb()
{

    $instance = XenForo_Application::getInstance();
    $dbConfig = $instance->getConfig()->db2;
    return $instance->loadDb($dbConfig);
}
```

I can load and process sql in model.
I want use this database in Datawriter

Help me, please!
Thanks